# Reading / writing to USB storage on a Pi

Tags: usb, readwrite, file

I set up my Raspberry Pi about 6 months ago, (October) and everything seemed to be working fine where I could using Tight VNC to remotely access it and download torrents e.t.c.

However, eventually the USB drive that was attached to the Pi starting acting up, and now any downloads or files I save to the drive don't actually save. There are now two listings for the same drive in the `/media` folder. One is the original name, and the other is the same name but with a `_` (underscore) at the end of it.

Is this why I can't read/write files correctly? It's trying to access the wrong file path because the name got cloned somehow? I will add screenshots later I am unfortunately (not really) at work right now.

Comment: what is output of running "mount" at the command line? and is the dual entries consistent between reboots and replugs of the drive?